# Xcode Trigger Action after Cell is Clicked in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am relatively new to programming in general (this is my first year learning it at school) so please explain in as easy a way to grasp as possible.

I am using UITableViewController to create a table view and I want to be able to add a string to a cell if it is empty (I think I have to add it to the array "phrases", but correct me if I am wrong) and display the contents of the cell if it contains a string. I know it has something to do with NSIndexPath but I don't know where to put the code.

```
class MyPhrases: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

var phrases = []

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return phrases.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!
    cell.textLabel
    return cell
}
```

}

Sorry if I messed up the formatting of the code this is my first question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like `cell.textLabel.text = "test"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you have to declare your array with phrases strings:

```
var phrases = ["welcome to stackoverflow", "second phrase", "third phrase"]
```

And change your cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!
    cell.textLabel.text = phrases[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Index path describes the position of cell in table view. It has two important properties: row and section. Since your table view has only one section, you get the phrase to display from array by row number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
cell.textLabel.text = phrases[indexPath.row]
```

but you will also need some code elsewhere to populate the array.  for testing, you could try initialising the array - just to make sure you're seeing **something** in the tableView.  You can initialise the array like this

```
var phrases = ["first", "second", "third"]
```